# I want to create pay by QR code on 100 pesso use mercadopago API

Tags: php, rest

I want to do qr-code payment. Should create qr-code on 100pesso to user can pay it. For it I should create store and create "POS". I can't understand what I want to do then. https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/reference

```php
<?php

$url = 'https://api.mercadopago.com/users/'.$user_id.'/stores';

$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer '.$private_key,
  'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$data = '{
  "name": "Sucursal Instore",
  "business_hours": {
    "monday": [
      {
        "open": "06:00",
        "close": "23:00"
      }
    ],
    "tuesday": [
      {
        "open": "06:00",
        "close": "23:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "external_id": "SUC001",
  "location": {
    "street_number": "3039",
    "street_name": "Caseros",
    "city_name": "Belgrano",
    "state_name": "Capital Federal",
    "latitude": -32.8897322,
    "longitude": -68.8443275,
    "reference": "3er Piso"
  }
}';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
  echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I created store and got `external_store_id` from it.

then I created QR-code

```php
$data = array(
    "name" => "First POS",
    "fixed_amount" => true,
    "store_id" => $store_id,
    "external_store_id" => "SUC001",
    "external_id" => "SUC001POS001",
    "category" => $category
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.mercadopago.com/pos');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Authorization: Bearer ".$private_key,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

From there I got link on QR code,
but how can I get link on qr code to pay only 100 pesso?

Comment: So is your question that, you have a link to pay 100 pesos, and you're wondering how to turn that link into a QR code?

Comment: If so, you can find plenty of QR code libraries for PHP on packagist. Alternatively you can find an online service like https://www.qr-code-generator.com/

Comment: You just set up your Point of Sale so far then. So I guess you will have to create an Order next - https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/reference/instore_orders/_mpmobile_instore_qr_user_id_external_id/post